# CakePHP using Sqlite instead of Mysql

Tags: sqlite, cakephp

CakePHP 4.0.0
CentOS 7

My `app_local.php` configuration uses Mysql Driver.

```
'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => Connection::class,
            'driver' => Mysql::class,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            ...
        ],

        'test' => [
            'className' => Connection::class,
            'driver' => Mysql::class,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            ....
        ],
    ],
```

However; I am failing to connect to the database. The debugger states that
`Connection to Sqlite could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file`.

This confuses me since I stated MySQL as the Driver..

My stack frame indicates that the connection to SQLite is for the Debug Panel.

Note: I've already installed the Sqlite Driver `yum install php56-php-pecl-sqlite.x86_64`.

Comment: See [here](https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/4/en/index.html#database-configuration) for configuring DebugKit's database connection.

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much. I should read more.

Comment: Know it's a little late, but offhand chance you remember your solution you can answer this yourself and close this. Might be of use to someone later still.